# How to change the color of an active link using CSS and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have tried this code working on this fiddle                              http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/sR3Ub/6/ and even others
       but it is not working fine on my xamp. Everything else is working but when i click a contact us or home, they become active for a second then faqs becomes active again. Please help me spot where i am going wrong.
And is there another way of telling users where they are apart from activating links?

MY .PHTML FILE

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="list-wrapper ">

    <li class="list-header">
        <a href="#a"  class="active">
        faqs
        </a> 
   </li>

    <li class="list-header">
        <a href="#b" >
          contact us
        </a> 
    </li>

    <li class="list-header">
        <a href="#c">
           about us
        </a> 
    </li>
</div>

    <script>
      $('a').on('click', function(){
        $('div.list-wrapper').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
     </script>
```

MY .CSS FILE

```
                 .list-wrapper { list-style: none;}
        .list-wrapper li { padding-left: 1em; text-indent: -.7em;}
        .list-wrapper li:before {
            content: "•  ";
            color: #C0C0C0; /* or whatever color you prefer */
        }

        .list-wrapper a:link,
        .list-wrapper a:visited   { color: #C0C0C0; text-decoration: none; }
        .list-wrapper a:hover  { color: #58595B; text-decoration: none; }
        .list-wrapper a.active,
        .list-wrapper a:active  { color: #E6BD13; text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: is this what you were trying to accomplish? http://jsfiddle.net/gx19ymws/

Comment: Try to clear your browser cache and reload the page

Comment: @Rick yes it is but it becomes in active after 1 second, i dont know why

Comment: yeah you got me.. its instant on this end..

Comment: @Rick i have also noted that  when i remove that jquery header still nothing changes. what could be wrong?

Comment: all I got left is clear your cache and try again.. otherwise what you are seeing is very hard to debug from where we are sitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the active class to the `li` not the `li a` and on clicking the li - clear the active class from all li's and then apply it to the clicked li.

The CSS is then based on changing the color of the `a` within the `li.active` rather than setting the active class on the a iteself.

Also - not sure why you are specifying list-style:none in one CSS rule - only to specify a list bullet in another.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.list-wrapper li').on('click', function(){
     $('.list-wrapper li').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
   })
});
```

```css
.list-wrapper { list-style: none;}
.list-wrapper li { padding-left: 1em; text-indent: -.7em;}
 .list-wrapper li:before {
   content: "•  ";
    color: #C0C0C0; /* or whatever color you prefer */
 }

.list-wrapper a:link,
.list-wrapper a:visited { color: #C0C0C0; text-decoration: none; }
.list-wrapper a:hover   { color: #58595B; text-decoration: none; }

.list-wrapper li.active a{ color: #E6BD13; text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="list-wrapper ">
    <li class="list-header active">
        <a href="#a">
        faqs
        </a> 
   </li>
   <li class="list-header">
        <a href="#b" >
          contact us
        </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="list-header">
        <a href="#c">
           about us
        </a> 
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: @gavgriff. the same behaviour is seen. But why? is it because i am on localhost or is it that when the page link reloads it losses focus? i dont know but the page i want  active becomes active for 1 second then goes back to normal color. the one selected by default is forever active

Comment: @gavgriff am i allowed to put all this in one file except the css part?